# PHP/CSS & Alignment of Columns

Tags: php, css

I started learning PHP/CSS/HTML5 & Java a month ago and I'm currently setting up an online shop for my new home business. I'm using opencart, but i'm having difficulty with transforming some of the PHP in terms of  getting it to display side by side.

This is how I would like it to look.

Price: $000.00000

```
<table width="200" border="0">
<tr>
<td>Option 1</td>
<td>Option 2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
 </table>
```

I've figured out how to do this in CSS, but the required radio radio buttons (see the code below) is the same code for option 1 & 2.

It currently looks like this

Price $000.0000

Option 1
1
2
3

Option 2
1
2
3

```
<?php if ($price) { ?>
  <div class="price">
    <span class="text-price"><?php echo $text_price; ?></span>
    <?php if (!$special) { ?>
    <span class="price-new"><?php echo $price; ?> <span style="font-size:10px;">pp</span></span>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <span class="price-new"><?php echo $special; ?></span><span class="price-old"><?php echo $price; ?></span> 
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if ($tax) { ?>
    <span class="price-tax"><?php echo $text_tax; ?> <?php echo $tax; ?></span>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if ($points) { ?>
    <span class="reward"><small><?php echo $text_points; ?> <?php echo $points; ?></small></span>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if ($discounts) { ?>
    <div class="discount">
      <?php foreach ($discounts as $discount) { ?>
      <?php echo sprintf($text_discount, $discount['quantity'], $discount['price']); ?><br />
      <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
   <?php if ($profiles): ?>
  <div class="option">
      <h2><span class="required">*</span><?php echo $text_payment_profile ?></h2>
      <br />
      <select name="profile_id">
          <option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
          <?php foreach ($profiles as $profile): ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $profile['profile_id'] ?>"><?php echo $profile['name'] ?></option>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
      </select>
      <br />
      <br />
      <span id="profile-description"></span>
      <br />
      <br />
  </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php if ($options) { ?>
  <div class="options">
    <h2><?php echo $text_option; ?></h2>
    <?php foreach ($options as $option) { ?>
    <?php if ($option['type'] == 'select') { ?>
    <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">
      <label><?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
      <span class="required">*</span>
      <?php } ?>
      <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b></label>
      <select name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]">
        <option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
        <?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
        <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
        (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
        <?php } ?>
        </option>
        <?php } ?>
      </select>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if ($option['type'] == 'radio') { ?>
    <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">
        <label>
      <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
      <span class="required">*</span>
      <?php } ?>
      <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b></label>
      <?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>

      <label class="radio" for="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>">
          <input type="radio" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" id="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" /><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
        <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
        (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
        <?php } ?>
      </label>
        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the help. I looked  dynamic tables in PHP and found a solution! Big learning curve ahead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you display your table dynamically and then simply style it in CSS using nth-child(#)? You can simply loop through an array and display echo each row before closing out the table after.